# Unicode char \u8:�tT not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: utf-8, latex, texmaker

I get the following error if i try to compile my LaTex file using TexMaker:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�tT not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.103 \maketitle
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
```

I posted my tex-file on CodePast.net :
http://codepaste.net/v3x41c

Here is the stylesheet I use:
http://codepaste.net/36kx6m

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You probably copied and pasted and invisible character (encoding issue).

Try **\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}** instead of utf8.